# "не будь её" - чем является в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, чем является фраза "не будь её" в предложении и согласно какому правилу здесь ставятся запятые.

*Сила эстетического воздействия русской природы так велика, что, не будь её, у нас не было бы ни таких блистательных поэтов, ни плеяды замечательных художников-пейзажистов,чьи картины неотъемлемы от лесных чащоб, ольшаников, прозрачных озёр нашей Родины.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

1) Синтаксические конструкции вида "не будь ее" часто встречаются в текстах,  например:

Перекладина спасла. Не будь ее ― покатились бы вместе (С. Я. Эфрон).

Не будь её, пошёл бы я в солдаты, только бы Титова избежать (Максим Горький).

"Не будь ее" определяет **условно-следственные** отношения между предикативными частями в сложном предложении, но **союза здесь нет**, поэтому логичнее считать, что это **бессоюзная связь** (ставится запятая или тире).

К примеру, к БСП относится предложение "Ужин не нужен, был бы обед".  Этот вариант также из общей темы **фразеологизованных конструкций со значением обусловленности.**

2) Вопрос **о постановке запятой в таких конструкциях также является спорным**, например:

Регент, придерживая дьячка за сюртучную пуговицу...пояснял ему в десятый раз, что жена его ангел и что **не будь ее**, он бы совсем погиб (В.А. Слепцов).

До того преследует, что, **не будь ее**, я не знаю даже, что бы мы делали и об чем бы думали! (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин).

Answer (score 2):

это придаточное условное. "будь" это не союз, а форма императива.
имеет место использование одного наклонения в функции другого (императив, оновная функция - повелевание - используется как сослагательное наклонение с функцией ирреальности "если бы ее не было ...")

Answer (score 2):

**Синтаксис всего предложения: бессоюзное сложное с условным значением.
Грамматическая форма: повелительное наклонение в роли условного.**

Эквивалент конструкции "если бы (не)... , (то) (не) (произошло) бы" (с соответствующим синтаксическим управлением).

Ничего специфического в конструкции "не будь её" нет.
Аналогично: 
сделай (он), решись (он) т. п.:

*Я почувствовал, что, **сделай он в самом деле сейчас гримасу**, ― я с ужасом, но в ту же секунду повторил бы ее на своем лице. [А. И. Куприн.
Лунной ночью (1893)]*

***Сделай он шаг***, и, пожалуй, всё может произойти! [А. П. Чехов.
Безотцовщина (1887)]

*По-моему, это мало что свинство, но это даже не расчет коммерческий:
**сделай он обед у Дюссо**, пусть он ему стоит полторы ― две тысячи, но
устрой самое дело, которое, может быть, впоследствии будет приносить ему
сотни тысяч. [А. Ф. Писемский. Мещане (1877)]*

*Ибо **решись он на какой-нибудь город**, и вмиг предприятие его стало бы в собственных его глазах и нелепым и невозможным; он это очень предчувствовал. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Бесы (1871-1872)]*
(все из нацкорпуса)
и подобное.

Аналогичные конструкции можно трактовать и как условное изъявительное наклонение:

> Повелительное наклонение может употребляться в значении условного и
>       изъявительного: Не подоспей боеприпасы — бой захлестнется без огня!
>       Крикни я громче, он бы услышал (т. е. если бы не подоспели
>       боеприпасы, если бы крикнул громче).

http://online-language.ru/blog/aspect-of-verb/

Единственным специфическим моментом в конструкции "не будь её" является отсутствие ярко выраженного подлежащего (агенса), но это связано не о особенностями синтаксиса предложения, а со спецификой формы *"(у меня) есть что-то", "(там) [есть] что-то"* выражающее агенс через косвенный падеж при отрицании (**"нет чего-то, не было чего-то"**). Но это здесь совершенно не существенно для понимания синтаксиса и грамматической структуры вообще.

Остальное - у Веры (примеры) и у Сержа (ссылка).

Answer (score 1):

Глагольная форма "будь" представляет собой императив, употребленный в функции сослагательного наклонения; само же предложение представляет собой условное придаточное, запятые ставятся на том же основании, что и в придаточных условных.

Об таком употреблении можете прочитать здесь: [Употребление форм повелительного наклонения с другими модальными значениями](http://sci-book.com/russkiy-yazyik/upotreblenie-form-povelitelnogo-nakloneniya-48208.html)

В.В. ВИНОГРАДОВ. РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК. ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЕ УЧЕНИЕ О СЛОВЕ. МОСКВА - 1986, 1986

Comment: Серж, а где подчинительный союз с условным значением?

Comment: Вера, императив здесь употреблен вместо подчинительного союза. Ср.: "Обзаведись они вовремя шутами (надо хотя бы от дурака слышать правду), может быть, им удалось бы продержаться ещё некоторое время"

Comment: Здесь тоже нет союза. В таких предложениях императив выступает вместо союза.

Comment: А если НЕТ СОЮЗА, значит, предложение БЕССОЮЗНОЕ. Думаю, что такой анализ - "выступает вместо союза, замещает союз" - неточен.  Одни и те же условно-следственные отношения можно передать СИНОНИМИЧНЫМИ конструкциями (СПП, ССП, БСП). Вид предложения - это его общая модель, а грамматическое значение предложения (смысловые отношения между предикативными частями), кроме союзов, могут выражать структурные  элементы, в данном случае форма императива для сказуемого.

Comment: Вера, бессоюзное внутри придаточного?

Comment: Может быть, тогда не надо ставить запятую после союза "что", например: "Иногда приходила мысль, что не будь их, он не поехал бы в эту последнюю экспедицию, так резко перевернувшую все в его жизни". Нужна здесь запятая? Интонационно предикатив явно не обособляется.

Comment: Нет, Вера, про запятую это уже фантазии. Серж прав по сути в трактовке, это императиы в роли условия, он дал хорошую ссылку. Только он не в курсе систематики сложных предложений, в этой части вы правы, а он косячит. И поэтому, конечно, нельзя никак считать, что "нечто заменяет союз", тут тоже Вы правы. Никакого подчинительного союза тут не требуется.

Comment: behemothus, а какому типу предложения Вы относите данное предложение?

Comment: Вера, допустим без запятой.  "Иногда приходила мысль, что не будь их, он не поехал бы в эту последнюю экспедицию, так резко перевернувшую все в его жизни". Вы относите данное предложение к бессоюзному?

Comment: И еще: говоря: " заменяет союз'' я не имею в виду, что в предложении императив надо считать союзом.

Comment: behemothus, а какому типу предложения Вы относите данное предложение? ------ Ну Вера же сказала, ССП. Не бывает по (совремнной классификации по крайней мере) в русском языке "бессоюзных сложноподчиненных". И "опущенных союзов" не бывает (ну в полноценно грамотной речи). Тут смысл в том, что тип _предложения_ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТСЯ типом _союза_. И никак иначе.

Comment: А где тогда сочинительный союз? Кстати, Валгина и Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов (Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976) относят такие предложения к придаточным условным.

Comment: behemothus, ССП внутри придаточного? Ведь оно стоит пoсле союза что.

Answer (score 0):

Это придаточное предложение со значением условия. *Будь* в данном предложении выступает в роли союза, семантика которого равнозначна нейтральному союзу условия *если*. Вот схема: [что, не будь (=если),...]. Так как перед последней запятой нет *то*, запятая перед *не будь* ставится.

См. другое оформление вашего предложения, при котором запятая бы не ставилась.

> Сила эстетического воздействия русской природы так велика, что не будь её, то у нас не было бы ни таких блистательных поэтов, ни плеяды замечательных художников-пейзажистов, чьи картины неотъемлемы от лесных чащоб, ольшаников, прозрачных озёр нашей Родины.

Подробнее об этом можно [почитать](http://best-language.ru/zapjataja-na-styke-dvuh-sojuzov) здесь. Источник информации малоизвестный, но вам будет полезно, надеюсь.

Comment: _"...что не будь её, **то** у нас не было бы..."_ === Это не по-русски!

Comment: Автор не спрашивает, по-русски ли это. Я объяснил грамматическую сторону вопроса, что и требовалось в задании.