# Сослагательное наклонение – как бы ...

Tags: наклонение

*Она посмотрела на пьяную подругу и ужаснулась: **как бы она сейчас и на самом деле не сняла платье.***

Как я понимаю, во второй части предложения используется сослагательное наклонение. Ищу материал с подробным объяснением его использования в таких структурах, но к сожалению ничего не нашла... Я правильно понимаю, сосл. накл. здесь используется для выражения действия, которое потенциально может осуществиться?

Имеют такие структуры какие-нибудь стилистические особенности? Хочу сказать, они более характерны для разговорной речи или это никакой роли не играет?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ага! "На протяжении следующих трёх лет я буду Вам надоедать со сослагательным наклонением... пока не закончу свою работу", значит! Да мы нарисуем примеры, за нами не заржавеет. А за Вами - подведение теоретической базы.

Comment: дорогая Galina, поверьте мне пожалуйста, я не лентяи и прикладываю максимум усилия, чтобы понять свою тему и все, что с неи связано. просто многие вещи функционируют в моем родном языке и в русском по-разному и я вижу, что шесть месяцев практики в России были недостаточны, чтобы взять с собой все необходимые мне знания. вот поэтому я и мучаю Вас всех : )

Comment: Для испанки у вас очень хорошие знания, излагаете Вы мысли грамотно, не делаете ошибки в окончаниях. А русский достаточно сложный язык, намного сложнее, чем испанский. Продолжайте заниматься в таком же темпе, у вас все получится.

Comment: Anonym'очка! Я и не думала, что Вы - "лентяи", боже упаси, это у меня стиль такой, немножко ёрнический... ))) И так как я - практик, а не теоретик, действительно могу что-нито нарисовать. Люблю русские диалекты, но какие именно использую, не знаю! )))

Answer (score 4):

Сослагательное наклонение может выражать желательность или нежелательность действия, например: Как бы поскорее добраться до дому! Как бы дождь не пошел!

Стиль у этой формы нейтральный.

Answer (score 2):

Сослагательное (условное) наклонение указывает на то, что действие возможно только при определенных условиях (образуется при помощи добавления частицы бы (б) к глаголу в форме прошедшего времени).

Нужно смотреть тему "Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении".

Пример я нашла: "Да я хотел вчера доложить: бороны починить бы надо". Это сослагательное "бы" я влепила в Толстого от себя: так я чувствую язык.  )))

И "как бы (чего не вышло)" мне кажется стилистически сниженным. Нейтральным было бы в приведённом случае "...и ужаснулась: неужели она сейчас и на самом деле снимет платье?".

[Существуют три случая, когда между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения нужно поставить двоеточие:](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)

> 1) если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой
>   части, например: В развитых странах средний класс решает исход
>   выборов: он составляет большинство населения. В это предложение можно
>   вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО;
>
> 2) если после первой части следует пояснение того, о чем идет речь в
>   первой части, например: Напишите план работы: что нужно закупить и
>   подготовить, с чего требуется начать, в какие сроки возможно
>   завершение проекта» или Как все московские ваш батюшка таков: желал бы
>   зятя он с звездами да с чинами (Грибоедов). В эти предложения между
>   частями можно вставить союз А ИМЕННО;
>
> 3) если вторая часть имеет значение дополнения, и перед ней можно
>   вставить союз ЧТО, например: Да я хотел вчера доложить: бороны
>   починить надо (Толстой).
>
> В некоторых случаях, кроме этого союза, в предложение можно добавить и
>   пропущенное сказуемое И УВИДЕЛ или И УСЛЫШАЛ, например: Он заглянул в
>   комнату: за столом сидел человек и что-то быстро писал.

"Наш" пункт 2. Допускаю, что и 3 годится... И везде можно "перевести" примеры в сослагательное наклонение.

У [Валгиной](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-199.htm) можно почитать о причинно-следственной (условно-следственной?) связи между частями предложения:

> ...группу бессоюзных сложных предложений образуют такие, которые в
>   смысловом отношении приближаются к сложноподчиненным предложениям:
>   между частями этих бессоюзных предложений существуют отношения
>   объектные, определительные, причинно-следственные,
>   условно-следственные и т.д. Сближает бессоюзные сложные предложения
>   этого типа со сложноподчиненными также и то, что обычно в этих случаях
>   одна из частей предложения, входящая в состав бессоюзного предложения,
>   содержит основную часть высказывания (условно ее можно было бы
>   приравнять к главной части в составе сложноподчиненного), а другая
>   (или другие) поясняет, раскрывает содержание первой (условно ее можно
>   было бы приравнять к придаточной части).

Ещё. Возьмём цитату из навеки пубертатного сочинителя Паустовского:

> Своими моральными качествами, талантливостью и творческой силой наш
>   народ обязан, среди других причин, и нашей природе. Сила ее
>   эстетического воздействия так велика, что, не будь ее, у нас не было
>   бы такого блистательного Пушкина, каким он был.

Запросто переделывается на сослагательное:

"Сила ее эстетического воздействия весьма велика: не будь ее, у нас не было бы такого..."

Идея с "не будь её" ("сослагающим") подгляжена [ТУТЪ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418180/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Answer (score 2):

Она посмотрела на пьяную подругу и ужаснулась: как бы она сейчас и на самом деле не сняла платье.

```
 сосл. накл. здесь используется для выражения действия, 
  которое потенциально может осуществиться.
```

Вы правы,и это потенциально возможное действие ужасает героиню.

То, чего боится говорящий/думающий, относится к миру нереализованных ситуаций,ирреальных, таких, которые лишь могут стать реальными.

Как бы не — изъяснительный  союз. употр. при выражении опасения, боязни чего- л. Союз употребляется в придаточных изъяснительных (что, видимо, Вас и смутило)

Но сослагательное наклонение употребляется не только в условных придаточных, но и в изъяснительных, и даже в придаточных цели (Он едет во Францию, чтобы любоваться собором Парижской Богоматери).Здесь частица бы  "приклеилась "к союзу что. Ваше предложение тоже возможно переделать в СПП с изъяснительным: ...ужаснулась,как бы она сейчас и на самом деле не сняла платье. Частица КАК усилила эмоции (Сравн.: испугалась, не сняла бы  сейчас платье  и на самом деле. )

Вот ещё сослагательное наклонение выражает значение опасения: Боюсь, брусничная вода мне не наделала б вреда (А. Пушкин).

В простых предложениях оно обозначает желательную (или нежелательную) для говорящего ситуацию: Дали бы ему денег на поездку во Францию!

Еще сослагательное наклонение используется для выражения мягкого побуждения: Отдал бы ты деньги по-хорошему.